# Unable connect using gnus to gmail

Tags: gnus

currently I'm trying to connect to my gmail.com account via gnus.

Following [emacswiki.org: Gnus#Gmail Quickstart](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#toc1) guide I get

```
nnimap (gmail) open error: 'NO (ALERT) Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)'.  Continue? (y or n) n 
Couldn't open server on gmail
```

Searching suggested page by google did not provide solution I could use.

Where did I went wrong?

Comment: Not really a gnus questions: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/WUaXHSdI3WM

Comment: @ErikHetzner following that I was able to make it work. If you post it as an aswer I will accept it as solution.

Comment: I don't use 2-step verification I still have the same issue.

Comment: @mfcabrera You might be required to use it by google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a gnus question, but the problem is 2 factor authentication in gmail. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/WUaXHSdI3WM explains the issue and how to fix it (you need to create an application specific password).

Comment: Nah, the problem is EmacsWiki moldering. Without a voting system to send those nefarious outdated docs in the abyss, this website is to be *avoided*.

Comment: @yPhil If only there were some way to update those outdated docs...

Answer (score 3):

This "quickstart guide" article you are following is probably outdated ; Here is [a recent document about using Gnus using oauth2 with 2 steps authorization](https://github.com/kensanata/ggg).